# How can I download google drive folders with batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to do `powershell.exe -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile winrar.exe https://www.rarlab.com/rar/winrar-x64-58b4.exe"` but instead of downloading WinRAR, download a file from google drive. The issue I'm having, is that there are ampersands (&) in the urls, and I can't find a way around those. It works fine in powershell itself, but when using the command listed above, it doesn't. So far adding quotations around the entire url hasn't worked, adding (^) in front of the ampersand hasn't worked, and quotations only around the ampersand hasn't worked.

Comment: on the `&` comment, we escape those using a catet `^&` Here is a good [escape reference guide](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: Use, doublequotes, `"h**p://www.mysite.com/question&answer/index.html"`. Please note however that any `%` characters will need to be escaped with another, `%20` becomes `%%20`.

Comment: Use doublequotes, in both [tag:PowerShell] and the [tag:Batch-File], like this instead: `"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1vzaBhv9WKz3cWtpySPPk84qyzevGJrAL"`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I just wrote a .ps1 script and ran it, then deleted it in a batch file. `echo Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile %HOMEPATH%\download.rar "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=abcd1234EFGH" > %HOMEPATH%\run.ps1 powershell.exe -Command %HOMEPATH%\run del C%HOMEPATH%\run.ps1`